# C pointer format displaying useless characters

Tags: c, pointers, hex, printf, conversion-specifier

When trying to print a pointer, for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int a = 3;
    printf("The address : %p\n", &a);
    printf("As an hex   : %x\n", &a);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a `000000ac4f5ffd58` and the nice `4f5ffd58` (the first two characters mismatch is from unknown origin). It's just for comfort and beauty, the `%x` "works" to display it. Is there any way to have the correct (`0x4f5ffd58`) way to print my pointer (its format) ?

I'm using CLion (I resetted the settings), and here is the `CMakeLists.txt` associated with it :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(untitled C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
add_executable(untitled main.c)
```

Comment: Great! Sooo why are you writing here? Is there a question you want to ask? Please see [ask]

Comment: `%x` print integers. Apparently, in your environment, pointers are larger than integers, so your program is undefined -- you just were lucky to print something remotely useful. In another system you might print the upper part, `ac`...

Comment: In this case "works" is same as "invokes undefined behaviour that apprently seem to create some useful result". Using format specifier `%x` for pointers is just illegal. Using `int*` as parameter for format specifier `%p` does the same. You must cast to `void*`

Comment: Why do you think it "works"? It's printing a different value because the first 2 digits are missing. It's printing the low-order 32 bits of the pointer value, but there are more bits in the pointer.

Comment: `Is there any way to have the correct way to print my pointer` Please define exactly "correct". For correctness as in defined behavior according to C programming standard, you should be using `"%p", (void*)&a)`, which will result in implementation-defined representation. The result you are getting tho - `000000ac4f5ffd58` - looks super very "correct". You want to print the value of the pointer in hex excluding leading zeros?

Comment: Write your own function that formats pointers.

Comment: The "correct" way I was thinking of it the `0x4f5ffd58`.

Answer (score 1):

> The "correct" way I was thinking of it the `0x4f5ffd58`.

What is the "correct" part of it? The length? If you're on a 64bit system, a 32bit value is by no means "correct".

If you're looking for the `0x` intro, you might want to try the "alternative" format (`printf("The address : %#p\n", (void *)&a);`). What exactly the standard and the alternative format might be is implementation-defined, but usually the alternative form provides the `0x` intro.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the conversion specifier `x` designed to output objects of the type `unsigned int`. Using it with a pointer invokes undefined behavior. Instead you could write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int a = 3;

    printf( "The address : %p\n", ( void * )&a );
    printf( "As an hex   : %#" PRIxPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )&a );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
The address : 0x7ffe9bf5f9b8
As an hex   : 0x7ffe9bf5f9b8
```

Also bear in mind that according to the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> **p** The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
> **implementation-defined manner**.

And pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Only the second `printf` actually print the `0x` prefix on my machine.

Comment: @DiraD When the conversion specifier p is used then the output has an implementation-defined form.

Comment: Do you know how I did (it the problem came from between the keyboard and the chair) to modify this form ? I can't recall doing that, but is there any way to transform it back ?

Comment: @DiraD I have not understood what you mean. If you need the prefix 0x when use the second call of printf shown in my demonstrative program.

Comment: It's more about "having the right display with the default call" than just having a "something that works"

Comment: @DiraD What is the "right display with the default call"?! I showed you correct calls of printf using a pointer as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was in my expectation.
In every C tutorial, the pointers is printed with the format `0x4f5ffd58`, but of course, as I redid every calculation now, 8*4 only makes a 32-bit address, where my system is a 64-bit, thus the longer displayed address (which confused me because I was first printing with the `0x` prefix, but no more, maybe due to an IDE update).